# I've managed to create a node tree that creates cables between two objects. How can I make it for multiple objects?

Tags: animation-nodes

Not sure if you guys are familiar with the TopoWire plugin for C4D ([see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7pefHWXbIo)), but I've managed to create a node tree in animation nodes that does this (without any dynamics).

Here's the node tree:
[image]

Now I have 2 question (that I guess are closely related):

1. How can I make this work for a Group of Objects?
2. How can I randomize the start and end points of the splines, while remaining in the object volume?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! You should add the things you have tried to your question, that way we know exactly how to help you.